# C++ Run a command detached from its parent so the parent can die w/o killing its child

Tags: c++11, embedded-linux, yocto

Since last week I fail to implement an update feature for my program. I've packaged all into *.ipk files so it can be installed/updated with the package manager opkg.

The package itself is systemd aware and will stop/disable start/enable restart the service as it deems necessary.

The script itself calls opkg install as the only important part. Everything else is for debugging purposes, which did not help at all.

```
if ( fork() == 0 ) {
    setsid();

    if ( fork() == 0 ) {
        setsid();
        setpgid(0, 0);
        daemon(0, 0);
        execl("/etc/ifmii/scripts/update.sh", (char*)0);
    } else {
        wait(nullptr);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20000));
        _exit(0);
    }
}
```

The code above is the result of my trials. The forks do fork, but it does not detach properly from its parent.

I can confirm, that the script and the install command is at least startet. But the Install fails.

I suspect the install fails because systemd stops the parent process calling the update command, and with it, all children die.

What else could i try? Is there something wrong with my approach? How does one normally do this?

*How do I run a command/script from a program which exits before the script/command it called exits?*

Comment: You can use std::atexit  to execute a command before the exit of a program.

Comment: But would this approach not have the same result? I would register my function which calls the update command. This function would be called on exit, which must result in the same behavior, because the parent calls a command in a child process which will die if the parent dies?

Comment: On what platform? You can try pthread library on Linux.

Comment: First of, my code does run inside a thread. Pthread will create a thread too, which wont survive its process' death.

Comment: Methinks you want to read Stevens' [Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Programming_in_the_Unix_Environment). It covers exactly questions like this, in probably the best way possible. It is one of the *must have* books, much like TCPL or Kernighan/Pike's [The Unix Programming Environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unix_Programming_Environment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I think i've found an answer.

I use the system() call together with systemd-run. With this any command can be run completly unaware of any parent-child relationship.

```
                system("systemd-run opkg install --force-reinstall --force-downgrade --force-overwrite $(find /media -type f ! -path '*\\.*/*' -iname '*.ipk')");
```

No forking required. All of tehe code above replaces my initial code.

Comment: At least, you don't have to write any dodgy forking code. :-) - system() does fork internally, and calls sh to interpret the command arguments, which potentially can be a vector for a hacker.